# Nodes and relationships are not persisting

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to create nodes and relationships in my Neo4j database.  The nodes are created, because I can print out the node id's but they do not persist. The next phase of my program is to count the number of nodes in an index and that gives a NullPointerExpection error. I'm using Gephi to visualize the graph and it shows neither nodes nor relationships. How do I get the nodes to persist? Could this be because I have another method (not shown due to length) that is wrapped in a transaction, which calls these node creating methods? Thanks

Here is part of the code:

```
public class Neo4JGraphDbClass {

private String graphLocation = "D:\\testdb"  ;

private GraphDatabaseService graphDb ;
private IndexManager graphIndex ;

private Index<Node> property1;
private Index<Node> special_nodes ;

public Neo4JGraphDbClass() {}
public void createGraphDb() {
    graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(graphLocation) ;
    graphIndex  =  graphDb.index();
    property1  = graphIndex.forNodes("PROPERTY1");
    special_nodes = graphIndex.forNodes("SPECIAL_NODES");
}

public Node createAndIndex(Integer[] property1) {
    Transaction transaction0 = graphDb.beginTx();
    try {
        Node node =    graphDb.createNode();
        node.setProperty("PROPERTY1",property1) ;
        property1.putIfAbsent(node, "PROPERTY1", property1);
        System.out.println(node.getId());
        transaction0.success();
        return node;
    } finally {
        transaction0.finish();
    }
}

public Node createSpecialNodes(Integer name) {
    Transaction transaction1 = graphDb.beginTx();
    try {
        Node node = graphDb.createNode();
        node.setProperty("SPECIAL_NODE", name);
        special_nodes.add(node, "SPECIAL_NODE", name);
        transaction1.success();
        return node;
    }
    finally {
        transaction1.finish();
    }
}
public void addNodesToGraph(Integer preName, ArrayList<Integer[]> preProperty1) {
    //stuff to change preName into name and preProperty into property
Transaction transaction = graphDb.beginTx();
    try {
        Node specialNode = createSpecialNodes(name) ;
        Node previousNode = graphDb.getReferenceNode();
        for (int i = 0; i < property1.size(); i++) {
            Node currentNode =  createAndIndex(property1.get(i));
            previousNode.createRelationshipTo(currentNode, RelTypes.NEXT_MEASURE);
            currentNode.createRelationshipTo(specialNode,RelTypes.SAMPLE);
            previousNode = currentNode; }
        transaction.success();
    }
    finally {
        transaction.finish();
    }
}

public Integer countIndex() {
    Integer hitSize;
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    try {
        IndexHits<Node> hits = graphIndex.forNodes("PROPERTY1").get("PROPERTY1", "*");
        hitSize = hits.size();
        tx.success();
    }
    finally {
        tx.finish();
    }
    return hitSize;
}

public Integer indexSize(Integer lookup) throws NullPointerException{
    Integer hitSize;

    Transaction tx2 = graphDb.beginTx();
    try {

        IndexHits<Node> hits =  graphIndex.forNodes("PROPERTY1").query(lookup);
        hitSize = hits.size();
        tx2.success();
    }
    finally {
        tx2.finish();
    }
    return hitSize;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are committing the outer transaction? Why not show the wrapping method?

Comment: Yes, I am committing the outer transaction.  I didn't show the wrapping method because then I would have to explain the non-Neo4j stuff and risk making an already convoluted question worse.

Comment: can you show the wrapping method anyway? This code looks good so far.

Comment: Sure, added an abbreviated version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks ok. What's your query look like, i.e. how do you come to the conclusion that the data isn't persisted?

Comment: I ran a query to count all the indexed nodes in my property1 index which returned 0.  Also the query to search for specific integer (term) and it returned a nullpointerexception.  To make a long story short, I used Gephi to see if the nodes/relationships were there.  And I got nothing.  So I check Gephi with another neo4j database I have and the nodes/relationships were there.

Comment: You cannot do index.get("property1", "*"), use query(...) for that. Which query string resulted in NPE?

Comment: Thanks. I'll change that to query.  The query is an integer of 6 digits, 583392, and the property is an array of integers.

Comment: I switched to the Enterprise version and that seemed to help.